# Get viewers for Facebook Live Video without overrating

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I need to get a statistics about FB Live Video.
For the beginning I want just `live_views`, but later need reactions and likes also.

Facebook API Documentation writes that API requests rate is 200 requests per hour per active user.
If suppose that I need to do this for every active user, I can send requests at most once in 18 seconds. Which is not quite good for seeing anything in dynamics. Also user can have several videos, and almost 18 seconds will be too frequent.

Is there any safe way to make requests to get amont of viewers (I use `{live_video_id}/live_views`) more frequent than every 18 seconds? May be something with Webhooks?
Thanks!