# Facebook API not-limited calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On the [Rate Limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) page of FB API Docs there's a phrase

> Not all API calls are subject to rate limits so the number of calls you make may not match what you see in the rate limit tool.

However, I didn't manage to find a list of these calls, that don't hit the limits. Is there any? Or may be someone knows them from their own experience?

Comment: Why would you need to know? What API calls your app makes should depend on the app’s functionality, and not on “which API calls can I make in unlimited numbers” - right …?

Comment: @CBroe The thing is if I use the calls that are subject to limits, I will make them carefully, count them and so on. If they are not limited, I can make them as fast, as I need. And I really need, because I want to get statistics in dynamics, and if calls are limited, in the worst case I will be able to get info only once in 18 second, which is too long for me. I stated the problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597016/get-viewers-for-facebook-live-video-without-overrating

Comment: Pretty sure the API calls relevant for that are limited. And those limits are in place for a reason.